# Is it mandatory to make class node static while creating a tree class for tree data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, structure, nodes

I am using the tree data structure in order to solve specific problems during the tree data structure implementation in java I keep nodes in a class and make them as static because it was a bit of advice given on the internet but I am not sure whether it is mandatory to make it static and what are the advantages of making it static.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class tree{
     node root;
     static class node{
         int data;
         node left_child;
         node right_child;

         public node(int data){
             this.data=data;
            left_child=null;
            right_child=null;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should follow Java capitalisation standards. This means:

- the first letter of each word in a class name is capitalised `LikeThis`
- method names are in camel-case, `likeThis()`

The `static` keyword associates the variables with the **class** instead of a particular **instance** of a class. This is probably not what you want. A very basic implementation of a tree is:

```
class Tree {
    private Tree right;
    private Tree left;
    private int data;


// getters/setters/constructors etc
}
```

You then want to initialise this as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.setRight(new Tree());
    tree.setLeft(new Tree());
    tree.setValue(5);

    // continue as needed, probably use a loop though
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are using node as **nested class static**

```
 static class node{
         int data;
         node left_child;
         node right_child;

         public node(int data){
             this.data=data;
            left_child=null;
            right_child=null;
         }
     }
}
```

As this class is inside tree class.
If you want to remove static then, you have to create this Node class in a separate file and you can import that class in tree class.

For example, create these two classes in test package as follows

```
 package test;
 import test.Node;

 public class Tree {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Node node = new Node();
    }

  }
```

and Node class as

```
package test;

public  class  Node{
  int data;
  Node next;
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Node [data=" + data + ", next=" + next + "]";
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating node class in another file can we create it in the same java file